# Xamarin.Forms - Informative app layout suggestions / directions

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I am totally fresh to mobile developments and I would appreciate any guideline here. I am doing a simple informative application (texts, images, web links) for Android and iOS, that would look like presented on this image:
[Preferred app layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNOpu.png)

Explanation: Top bar with 4 buttons is always there. Buttons 1-3 are switching between 3 standalone pages, where 2 and 3 are simple (maybe with vertical scrolling), but page 1 has fixed header and a few horizontal sliding pages underneath. Button 4 implements a calling function to predefined number, no content.

What I did: After researching for a while I tried to do this the most simple and straightforward way possible. My main page (`ContentPage`) has buttons in Grid and `<ContentView x:Name="PageHolder">`) under them. On clicking buttons 1-3 I set PageHolder.Content to desired page (`PageHolder.Content = new B2Page().Content`), all 3 of them are also ContentPages. In page B1 I use  to combine fixead header elements with CarouselView (Xamarin.Forms.CarouselView 2.3.0-pre2), that enables horizontal sliding.

What I don't like: I created sliding pages in CarouselView using `<CarouselView.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate>` but I would like to have 5 pages with different layout here. I don't know how to achieve that. I also noticed too big heap usage when clicking buttons (I added pictures to each content page for testing), resulting in OOM exception, probably because new BxPage() is called many times. I tried to initialize all 3 pages once under main page but got same results so I'm not sure where this comes from.

I know this is quite long and maybe even a bit messy question but any answer or maybe just pointing into right direction (design-wise) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> page 1 has fixed header and a few horizontal sliding pages underneath. I would like to have 5 pages with different layout here.

You could try using [Xamarin.Forms TabbedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page), it consists of a list of tabs and a larger detail area, with each tab loading content into the detail area.

> where 2 and 3 are simple (maybe with vertical scrolling), button 4 implements a calling function to predefined number, no content.

You could use `Button 2`,`Button3` and `Button 4` as [ToolbarItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.toolbaritem?view=xamarin-forms). When you click the `ToolbarItem`, you can open page or execute the some function.
[Here](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/) is an example about how to use `ToolbarItem`.